# How to change Doxygen to not use ANY file extension?

Tags: uri, doxygen, file-extension

Doxygen's html file extensions default to `.html`.  I'm not so concerned about what the filenames are on disk--but the internal links in the pages will still have the extension.  This runs counter to the recommendations of [Cool URIs Don't Change](http://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/).

I did discover that there is a [HTML_FILE_EXTENSION](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_file_extension), which theoretically lets you change the extension to anything you want.  You can get it as far down as `.`--but you can't give them *no extension*.  Leaving it blank causes it to default back to `.html`.  :-/

It's of course easy that when you get ready to publish, you can switch the extension to `.strip-me-from-docs-for-publication`.  Then do a search/replace of that with nothing *(or `/` if you believe in trailing slashes in URLs, which I think I do)*.  In the meantime you'll be able to take advantage of browsing the generated docs locally without pushing them to the server.

I'm wondering if there's any kind of smoother way to approach the problem, skipping the search/replace step?

Comment: May I ask why you would like to remove the file extension completely? Is using a compile HTML (.chm), Eclipse help format or PDF a solution for you (see http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/output.html)?

Comment: @JonasWolf When I host the pages on the web, I would like the links inside those pages to not have an extension...so they're not decorated with .html (or anything at all).  On the server side, I can fetch the pages with any extension...even if the request didn't have one, that's easy.  But if the user hovers over a link and clicks "Copy Link Address"...they will get something with .html on their clipboard unless I can find a way to get it out of the page.  I'm asking if there's anything besides manual search and replace for this... (not hard, just an extra step)

Comment: Is mod_rewrite an option? You would not need to manipulate the output of doxygen then.

Comment: @JonasWolf I'm not sure how mod_rewrite can affect the link text inside the generated Doxygen page, where it says `<a href=".../xxx.html">`.  While I can make it so that if an inbound request for xxx.html comes in, and forward it so the URL bar shows something with no extension...that doesn't solve the "user copied the URL to clipboard from right clicking the link itself" problem.  I'd rather have no way to leak the `.html` into the environment...so what ultimately appears in the URL bar is not my only concern.

Comment: You are right, mod_rewrite sounds not appropriate. What about 'mod_proxy_html' and its 'ProxyHTMLURLMap'. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#page-header

Comment: @JonasWolf I'm not sure if setting it up is worth the hassle and performance cost in serving the pages vs just having a "deploy to server" step which does the search and replace one time.  Still that's a good suggestion, I didn't know there was a module specifically tailored to doing that correctly...perhaps you should add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using a script to rename doxygen output files and then search and replace the links within these files is the straight forward option.

Another way could be to use `mod_proxy_html` and its `ProxyHTMLURLMap` feature.
See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html

Maybe it has to be used in combination with `mod_rewrite`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite

Comment: Thanks for answering... seems like it is probably what there is, or something else would be in the documentation!  Still I'll leave it open a bit longer; seems Doxygen isn't the most-viewed tag. *(In the meantime, if you would like to see some other thoughts to check over, here's [my collective motivation behind asking](http://blog.hostilefork.com/low-commitment-doxygen-markup-cpp/)  :-P)*

Comment: Doxygen tag not too active on SO, I see :-/ a view a day.  I think we've pretty much found the limit here, though... accepting!